# Chamada de função Jquery no HTML criado via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Meu main.js e o meu html.

```js
$(function()
{
 /*var ipControlador;
 $(function carregaFlows()
 {
 $.getScript("indexFunction.js", function()
 {
  ipControlador = ip;
  alert(ipControlador);
 });
 });*/
 
 $("#in_port").change(function()
 {
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/core/switch/all/port/json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    var options = '<option value="#">Porta de saída</option> <option value="output=flood">output=flood</option>';
    $.each(data, function(key, val)
    {
     if(key == ($("#switch").val()))
     {
         var i = 0;
         while ( parseInt(val.port[i].portNumber) )
         {
          if($("#in_port").val() != val.port[i].portNumber)
          {
           options += '<option value="output='+val.port[i].portNumber+'">output'+val.port[i].portNumber+'</option>';
          }
          i++;
        }
     }
    });
    $("#actions").html(options);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro bicho : "+result.status);
   }
  });
 });
 
 $("#switch").change(function()
 {
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/core/switch/all/port/json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    var options = '<option value="#">Porta de entrada</option>';
    $.each(data, function(key, val)
    {
      if(key == ($("#switch").val()))
      {
       var i = 0;
       while ( parseInt(val.port[i].portNumber) )
       {
         options += '<option value="'+val.port[i].portNumber+'">'+val.port[i].portNumber+'</option>';
         i++;
       }
      }
    });
    $("#in_port").html(options);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro bicho : "+result.status);
   }
  });
 });

 $(function carregaFlows()
 {
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "GET",
   async: false,
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/core/switch/all/aggregate/json",
   success: function(dados)
   {
    var qtdFolws;
    $.each(dados, function(chave, valor)
    {
     qtdFlows = valor.aggregate.flowCount;
    });
   },
   error: function(dados)
   {
    alert("Deu erro bicho : "+result.status);
   }
  });

  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/list/all/json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    var linhas = '<tr><th>Switch</th><th>Nome</th><th>Cookie</th><th>Prioridade</th><th>Porta de entrada</th><th>Porta de saída</th>';
    var cont = 0;
    var nome;
    $.each(data, function(key, val)
    {
     for(var i = 0; i < qtdFlows; i++)
     {        
      for(index in val[i])
      {            
       if(eval('val[i].'+index+'.match.in_port') != 'controller')
       {
         nome = index;
         linhas += '<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+index+'</td><td>'+eval('val[i].'+index+'.cookie')+'</td><td>'+eval('val[i].'+index+'.priority')+'</td><td>'+eval('val[i].'+index+'.match.in_port')+'</td><td>'+eval('val[i].'+index+'.actions.output')+'</td><td><a href="#" class="excluir" id="'+index+'">Excluir</a></td></tr>';       
       }
      }
      cont++;
     }
    });
    $("#tabelaRotas").html(linhas);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro bicho : "+result.status);
   }
  });
 });
 
 
 $(function carregaDados()
 {
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/core/controller/switches/json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    var options = '<option value="#">Switchs</option>';
    $.each(data, function(key, val)
    {
     options += '<option value="'+val.switchDPID+'">'+val.switchDPID+'</option>';
    });
    $("#switch").html(options);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro bicho : "+result.status);
   }
  });
 });

 $("#rota").on("submit", function(event)
 {
  var form = (
   "{ " +
     '"switch": "' + $("#switch").val() +
     '", "name": "' + $("#name").val() +
     '", "cookie": "' + $("#cookie").val() +
     '", "priority": "' + $("#priority").val() +
     '", "in_port": "' + $("#in_port").val() +
     '", "active": "' + $("#active").val() +
     '", "actions": "' + $("#actions").val() +
   '" }');
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "POST",
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json",
   data: form,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    alert(data.status);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro : "+data.status);
   }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
 });
 $(".excluir").click(function()
 {
  var nome = this.id;
  alert(nome);
  /*var jsonExclui = ("{" + '"name": "'+nome+'" }');
  alert(jsonExclui);
  $.ajax(
  {
   method: "DELETE",
   //type: 'delete',
   url: "http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json",
   data: jsonExclui,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data)
   {
    alert(data.status);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    alert("Deu erro : "+data.status);
   }
  });*/ 
 });
});
```

```html
<hmtl>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Controlador</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="adicionaRotas.html">Adicionar Rota</a>
  <a href="gerenciaRotas.html">Gerenciar Rotas</a>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Gerenciar Rotas:</legend>
    <table border="0" id="tabelaRotas">
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <form method="GET" action="http://192.168.0.199:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/clear/all/json">
   <input type="submit" value="Apagar Flows de todos os switchs">
  </form>
 </body>
</hmtl>
```

É uma extensão (Chrome). O problema que enfrento ocorre no momento em que aperto no link que é criado dinamicamente: 
`<td><a href="#" class="excluir" id="'+index+'">Excluir</a></td>`.
O link não está chamando a última função do main.js.
O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para elementos criados dinamicamente, o `click` não funciona. Para funcionar, deve usar o método [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#tabelaRotas').on('click', '.excluir', function() {
     var nome = this.id;
     alert(nome);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.